# Preparations for Icecream sandwich and ACL usage

Tags: android

There was a post about preparations for `Andoid Icecream Sandwich` release on Android Dev blog and in particular adopting your tablet UI for handsets. What if I do want to make additional resources for handsets (now I have my app for xlarge screen sizes only) and follow their instructions - how can I really test the app until the mentioned OS is shipped? If I would use `Android Compatibility Library` for this - will I need to re-implement certain things when Icecream is released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I really test the app until the mentioned OS is shipped?

You can't. You can test how it works on older phone Android OS versions (assuming your app is designed to support Android 2.x devices in addition to Ice Cream Sandwich), but you cannot test on Ice Cream Sandwich until the Ice Cream Sandwich SDK and/or devices are available.

> If I would use Android Compatibility Library for this - will I need to re-implement certain things when Icecream is released?

Possibly, but hopefully not. It is impossible for us to say at this time, since we do not know what is in Ice Cream Sandwich and how it will behave. That being said, the advice given in [the blog post you cited](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html) is likely to be solid advice, or else they would not have posted it mere weeks before the SDK should ship.